# Using ffmpeg to copy metadata from one file to another

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata

I want to use ffmpeg to copy all meta data not associated with core aspects of a video (frame rate, resolution) from one video to another. Is there a simple way to do this with a single command?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use `-map_metadata`.

In this example the global and stream metadata will be copied from `in0.mkv`. The video and audio streams will be stream copied from `in1.mkv`:

```
ffmpeg -i in0.mkv -i in1.mkv -map 1 -c copy \
# copies all global metadata from in0.mkv to out.mkv  
-map_metadata 0 \
# copies video stream metadata from in0.mkv to out.mkv
-map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v \
# copies audio stream metadata from in0.mkv to out.mkv
-map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a \
out.mkv
```

This will result in something like:

```
Output #0, matroska, to 'out.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : Global Title
    AUTHOR          : Global Author
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264
    Metadata:
      title           : Stream 0 Title
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis
    Metadata:
      title           : Stream 1 Title
```

By default global metadata is copied from the first input file, so `-map_metadata 0` could probably be omitted.

Comment: If your source video is a .mov file you need to also add the flag `-movflags use_metadata_tags` or the output video won't contain the metadata.

Comment: It overwrites the output file.. Output file contains video from the input file now.. I would expect to leave the contents of the output file, just copy the metadata of the input file to output file.

Comment: @hipokito `ffmpeg` can't perform in-place editing. A new file must be created, and it will ask you if you want to overwrite any existing files.

Comment: Is `map_metadata` still required with ffmpeg 4.4 when there is only 1 input file? (For example if you want to optimise mp4 files with `movflag +faststart` while ensuring all metadata is also copied over tot he new file)?

Comment: @sfxedit No, you don't need `-map_metadata` for a single file. ffmepg will attempt to copy all metadata. I should update this old answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Note that the above only works for outputs with at most 1 video and 1 audio stream.  Outputs with multiple streams (including multiple video, audio, subtitle, or data streams) require 1 `-map_metadata:s` per stream to copy all per-stream metadata.  For example, for 3 subtitle streams: `-map_metadata:s:s:0 0:s:s:0 -map_metadata:s:s:1 0:s:s:1 -map_metadata:s:s:2 0:s:s:2`.

Comment: I had to remove the inline comments for it to work correctly.

Comment: You should use `-map_metadata 0` to keep "creation_time" metadata field. If you omit it, the result file will not have "creation_time" property even if you used `-c copy`. (ffmpeg 6.0)

Answer (score 3):

From the comment in the answer [How to make Handbrake preserve capture time / creation time?](https://superuser.com/questions/523286/how-to-make-handbrake-preserve-capture-time-creation-time/523696#comment2528176_523696)

A full command line adding the option to copy special tags will be:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i out.mp4 -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy -movflags use_metadata_tags fixed.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

For decoding Flac to AIFF whilst preserving metadata, this answer worked better for me: [Covert FLAC to AIFF while saving tags/metadata](https://superuser.com/questions/1493313/covert-flac-to-aiff-while-saving-tags-metadata)

Answer (score 0):

When using ffmpeg at a file which has metadata (like a title) in its streams, you need to use -map_metadata again, as it will not hold those metadata in the new output

Comment: nope. not right. wrong even.

Answer (score -3):

If all you need is the basics (creation date, etc), then
touch -r FILE1 FILE2
Will work as a charm coping metadata from FILE1 to FILE2

Comment: If you read the question, the objective is the video meta data, not the file meta data.