# Using ffmpeg to batch copy metadata from one file to another

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, metadata

I've seen some great articles on how to use ffmpeg to copy metadata from one file to another without re-encoding. But I have more than 100 files and would like to do this in a batch operation. Any suggestions?

Extra info: I have 2 folders, one contains the video files with correct metadata, the other contains the video files with incorrect metadata. The files have the same corresponding file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to give you a scripting answer, there may well be a more general tool for this.

For future readers, this script describes how to copy metadata: [Using ffmpeg to copy metadata from one file to another](https://superuser.com/questions/996223/using-ffmpeg-to-copy-metadata-from-one-file-to-another).

The following script will loop through the the files in one directory,
find corresponding files in a second directory and then combine these two files into a third output directory

```
dir1=FIRST DIRECTORY
dir2=SECOND DIRECTORY
output=OUTPUT DIRECTORY
for file in $(ls $dir1); do
  ffmpeg -i "$dir1/$file" -i "$dir2/$file" -map 1 -c copy \
   # copies all global metadata from in0.mkv to out.mkv  
   -map_metadata 0 \
   # copies video stream metadata from in0.mkv to out.mkv
   -map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v \
   # copies audio stream metadata from in0.mkv to out.mkv
   -map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a \
   "$outdir/$file"
done
```

The metadata mapping command is adapted from the quoted answer.

If you want to make something reuseable you could put this in a script
with the following header (remove the assignment for dir1, dir2 and output in the script above). And then call it as `script.sh dir1 dir2 outdir`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x errexit # exit immediately on error
dir1="$1"
dir2="$2"
output="$3"
```

Warning: I have no run any of these scripts.

Comment: Great! thanks for your helpful answer, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Output file is no longer the old video, it gets replaced with a copy of input file..