# Covert FLAC to AIFF while saving tags/metadata

Tags: linux, command-line, ffmpeg, conversion, flac

I need a command-line tool to convert a bunch of `XXX.flac` files to `XXX.aiff` while preserving the tags (artist, title, album, etc.). None of the tools I tried (ffmpeg, sox, flac) seem to do the job well. Here is an example:

```bsh
ygabuev@core:~/Music/2019 Sun Ra - Crystal Spears [FLAC]$ ffmpeg -loglevel info -i "01 - Crystal Spears.flac" -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 out.aiff
ffmpeg version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, flac, from '01 - Crystal Spears.flac':
  Metadata:
    ARTIST          : Sun Ra
    ALBUM           : Crystal Spears
    DATE            : 2019
    album_artist    : Sun Ra
    LABEL           : Modern Harmonic
    UPC             : 0090771808226
    GENRE           : Jazz
    disc            : 1
    track           : 01
    TRACKTOTAL      : 04
    ISRC            : USCWY1800460
    TITLE           : Crystal Spears
    DISCTOTAL       : 1
  Duration: 00:06:09.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 750 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 600x600 [SAR 96:96 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> png (native))
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (flac (native) -> pcm_s16be (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x55bc89a85c40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[aiff @ 0x55bc8999bc00] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
Output #0, aiff, to 'out.aiff':
  Metadata:
    ARTIST          : Sun Ra
    ALBUM           : Crystal Spears
    DATE            : 2019
    album_artist    : Sun Ra
    LABEL           : Modern Harmonic
    UPC             : 0090771808226
    GENRE           : Jazz
    disc            : 1
    track           : 01
    TRACKTOTAL      : 04
    ISRC            : USCWY1800460
    TITLE           : Crystal Spears
    DISCTOTAL       : 1
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgb24(progressive), 600x600 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 90k fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      comment         : Cover (front)
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 png
    Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_s16be (NONE / 0x454E4F4E), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc57.107.100 pcm_s16be
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=   63578kB time=00:06:09.06 bitrate=1411.2kbits/s speed= 796x    
video:579kB audio:63578kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown


(base) ygabuev@core:~/Music/2019 Sun Ra - Crystal Spears [FLAC]$ ffprobe out.aiff 
ffprobe version 3.4.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Copyright (c) 2007-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.18.04.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, aiff, from 'out.aiff':
  Metadata:
    title           : Crystal Spears
  Duration: 00:06:09.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16be, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
```

It can be seen that after conversion the only remaining tag is "title".

Can I do the job with ffmpeg or sox alone? Or should I use some other converting/tagging tools? What can you recommend?

My setup: Ubuntu 18.04.3, ffmpeg 3.4.6, sox v14.4.2.

Comment: @llogan I have updated the question

Answer (score 6):

Add `-write_id3v2 1` output option. This is off by default for the AIFF muxer. See `ffmpeg -h muxer=aiff`.

```
ffmpeg -i input.flac -write_id3v2 1 -c:v copy output.aiff
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you!

Comment: Wish they had this for alac