# How do I prevent FFmpeg from replacing all the audio stream names with SoundHandler?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, audio-conversion

I'm using FFmpeg to change a video container from mkv to mov with this code:

```
ffmpeg -find_stream_info -probesize 84M -i input_file.mkv 
-map 0:v -map 0:a -map -0:s -codec copy output_file.mov -loglevel error;
```

But **all the audio streams get "SoundHandler" as name/handler after the conversion**.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX73g.jpg)
How can I preserve the original names?
[This is what I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkvrW.jpg)

I tried adding this:

`-metadata:s:a handler_name='' -empty_hdlr_name 1`

It should tell FFmpeg to not use the default 'SoundHandler' name and use instead a empty string, which means it should take the original stream name I guess.
But it only get the first audio stream correctly, the others get the same handler as if every stream was the first one...
Is there any solution?

Comment: Wait, but `handler_name` is _not_ the stream name field... What metadata does `ffprobe` or `mkvinfo` show for the original vs the output?

Comment: The input audio stream looks like this:
`Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp Metadata: title: Commentary with filmmaker William Friedkin`
The Output looks like this: 
`Stream #0:3[0x6](eng): Audio: aac (HE-AAC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 70 kb/s Metadata: handler_name : SoundHandler vendor_id : [0][0][0][0]` As you can see the title information is lost... I just wanted a pure copy of the original

Comment: Okay, but in the original you show, the stream name is *definitely* not in the "handler_name" field – it's in the "title" field. So when FFmpeg sets handler_name, that's got zero effect on stream title.

Answer (score 0):

> replacing all the audio stream names with SoundHandler?

It's not *replacing* the names – the text "SoundHandler" **goes in a different metadata field** than the title. The problem is really that the `title` metadata field is not being copied at all.

According to [Using ffmpeg to copy metadata from one file to another](https://superuser.com/questions/996223/using-ffmpeg-to-copy-metadata-from-one-file-to-another#comment2225946_996278), you will likely need to:

1. Use `-map_metadata 0` to copy global metadata;
2. Use `-map_metadata:s:v 0:s:v` and `-map_metadata:s:a 0:s:a` to copy video and audio stream metadata;
3. Use `-movflags use_metadata_tags` to force metadata to be written because your output is a MOV file.